# A More Efficient Embedding Method for YouTube Videos

Tags: media, files

I have created a video gallery comprised of embedded YouTube videos using the Media: YouTube Module. Everything works as expected, but the page load is slow. This is a common issue when embedding many YouTube videos on a page.

Amit Agarwal proposed this [solution](http://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/) on his blog which drastically reduces load time. Is there a way to do this with the current Module or custom scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can essentially follow that approach in Drupal.  I have used a variant on it.

In a `MYTHEME_preprocess_html()`, do a `drupal_add_js()` to load in the YouTube Javascript API.

Field out the video media type to add an image if you don't want to use the default YouTube thumbnail.

Create and edit media-youtube-video.tpl.php for your theme; the default is in the media_youtube module folder.  Make the markup match what you want.

Write a `MYTHEME_preprocess_media_youtube_video()` function to add in any addtional `$variables` that you may need in your template, like the image if you added one.

Then add a Javascript behavior to `.media-video-wrapper` so that when the user clicks on the thumbnail, the YouTube video is dynamically created.  You probably also want to add some logic to destroy other videos on the page.

This is actually way easier than it sounds if you are comfortable with PHP for themes.